# Python requests from google return in hebrew

Tags: python

When I use (from an israeli IP address):

```
requests.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin')
```

The response is in hebrew (the same can be seen in the browser in incognito mode)

I want to somehow specify to the get method, a parameter which means "I want to get the response in english".

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
requests.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?lp=1&hl=en')
```

(note the language selector on the bottom)